# client connection can not established

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I have a problem with my clients. I used threads to have multiple connections to my server.The clients should connect to the server and talk to each other. The problem is they can't connect to the server.

This is my code:

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include<pthread.h>

typedef struct{
 int portno;
 int sockfd;
 const char *ip;
 const char *username;

 }clients;

clients client;

int server_connect()
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in server;

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock == -1)
    {
      errx(1, "Could not create socket");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);

  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client.ip);
  server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port        = htons(client.portno);

  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        errx(1, "Connect failed. Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  fprintf(stdout, "Connected to server\n");

  client.sockfd = sock;

  pthread_t send_thread, receive_thread;

  if (pthread_create(&send_thread, NULL, send_message, (void *) &client.sockfd) < 0)
    errx (1, "can not create send thread");

  if (pthread_create(&receive_thread, NULL, receive_message, (void *) &client.sockfd) < 0)
    errx (1, "can not create receive thread");

  pthread_join(send_thread, NULL);
  pthread_join(receive_thread, NULL);

  close(sock);

  return 0;
}
```

send_message() & receive_message()

```
void *send_message()
{
   char buffer[256], log[256];

   snprintf(log, sizeof log, "user %s is joined.", client.username);
   if (send(client.sockfd, log, sizeof log, 0) < 0)
    errx(1, "Send failed");

   while (1) {
     fprintf(stdout, "%s","> ");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

     if (send(client.sockfd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0) < 0) {
      errx(1, "Send failed");
     }
   } 
  }  

  void *receive_message() {
   while (1) {
    char server_reply[2000];
    if (recv(client.sockfd, server_reply, 2000, 0) < 0) {
         errx(1,"recv failed");

    }
    //Receive a reply from the server
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", server_reply);
   }
 }
```

Some section of the code is not mine and I found it with search. Would you please help me to find the mistake?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code is impossible to debug. You did not provide a minimal, working example (e.g. no `#include`s, so your code does not even compile) and you did not post the error messages or any explanation of your attempts to make this work. Please consider improving your question so we can help you!

Comment: Borken anyways for the usual reasons: failure to correctly and completely handle the results returned by system calls like recv(), calling library functions that require  NUL terminated char arrays with arguments that are not guaranteed NUL terminated...

Comment: @Daniel Schütte Thanks for reply. I added include files. I don't have any error message, When I run the client it dose not show the prompt write the message.

Comment: You're missing a `main` function here. This is probably library code you (as you said above) copy-pasted from somewhere - but it never gets called anywhere. In C, an executable binary needs a `main` function as an entry point. It is natural that nothing happens when you try to execute your program.

Comment: regarding: `void *send_message()`  and `void *receive_message()`  These are not valid signatures for threads. Please read the MAN page for threads

Comment: what is the contents of function: `errx()`?

Comment: Since the server is also part of your project, please post the contents of that application

Comment: a valid signature for your threads would be: `void *send_message( void *arg )` and the first statement in the body should be: `sock_t sock = *( sock_t*)arg;`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to obtain the same results

Comment: when calling `inet_addr()`, need the following header files: `#include <sys/socket.h>` and `include <netinet/in.h>` and `#include <arpa/inet.h>`

Comment: regarding: `server.sin_port        = htons(client.portno);`  The function: `htons()` is expecting a parameter of type: `uint16_t` but the actual parameter being passed is of type `int32_t` (I.E. `int`) which can result in an erroneous value being set into the `client` struct

Comment: At the end of the threads, is the statement: `return 0;` which (usually) will work, however, much better to use: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: the posted code fails to set the fields of the struct: `clients`.  this is probably the main reason the posted code is not working.   Also, most debuggers use the `tag` name of the struct to be able to display the individual fields within the struct, Therefore, strongly suggest adding a `tag` name to each struct definition

Comment: regarding: `bzero(buffer,256);
     fgets(buffer,255,stdin)`   1) do not use 'magic' numbers. rather give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names (perhaps via a `#define` statement) then use those meaningful names through out the code.  2) no need to call `bzero()`  (a depreciated function) as the call to `fgets()` will properly handle the whole operation.  Note: always check `(!=NULL) the returned value from `fgets()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `if (recv(client.sockfd, server_reply, 2000, 0) < 0) {`   The `recv()` function does not NUL terminate the input data, so need to use the returned value from `recv()` to terminate the string, before passing to `fprintf()`  Similar to: `ssize_t byteCount;  if ( ( byteCount = recv(client.sockfd, server_reply, 2000, 0) ) < 0) { // handle error } server_reply[ byteCount ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client.ip);`  The server `sockaddr_in` struct needs the IP address of the server, not the IP address of the client